# opencv camera calibration object_points orientation

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm working on an opencv project and following different sources which are books and some source codes. I found a difference between book and some source codes. When calibrating a camera using chessboard as known we define an object points which is made from corners of chessboard. For example left top corner is (0,0) and the next one is (0,1). But in book the coordinate system used as (y,x) while in source codes i found in internet its (x,y) as i gave in the example. right side is +x and down side is +y.

The code in book:

```
for (int i=0; i<boardSize.height; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<boardSize.width; j++) {
        objectCorners.push_back(cv::Point3f(i, j, 0.0f));
    }
}
```

The piece taken from source code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < board_height; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < board_width; j++)
        obj.push_back(Point3f((float)j * square_size, (float)i * square_size, 0));
```

Which one is correct?

Edit:

I checked next version of the book and writer uses the same loop in related part.

Comment: imho it depends on the 3D coordinate system you want to get.

Comment: The problem is everything is the same but this part. Same function cannot give different coordinate system output? @Micka

Comment: you mean input? The coordinate system you choose for your object points can be arbitrary. So it is up to you whether you want the longer side of the chessboard to be your x or y or z axis or a diagonal or anywhere else in the room.

Comment: Oh you say when i change the position of x and y the output also comes reversed?

Comment: Yes i mean input. Can you put your comment as an answer. @Micka

Comment: Should be the case, yes. Best you try it yourself, I'm only 99% sure about that :D

Comment: Hahaha, if you put your comment as an answer, i will close the topic and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinate system you choose for your object points can be arbitrary.

So it is up to you whether you want the longer side of the chessboard to be your x or y or z axis or a diagonal or anywhere else in the room.

You might only have to keep in mind the limitations to the used coordinate system. It is probably cartesian. That means if you choose the "wrong" order you will "look" from the wrong side to the object.
Maybe that's why they've experimentally chosen the different order in the book?

Comment: No object used in book. Its just an example code, cookbook style. Thank you for your answer. Enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

From the openCV Documentation on camera calibration found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html?highlight=point3f) when they are demonstrating the use of `Point3f`, a little more than half way down the page I have linked, they use it in the same way as the source code (j, i).

Code from documentation:

```
for( int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; ++i )
for( int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; ++j )
    corners.push_back(Point3f(float( j*squareSize ), float( i*squareSize ), 0));
```

I would mimic the documentation and take the book with a grain of salt but the better thing to do is to try both examples.

Comment: How do i understand from the results. They might be pretty close. Comparin their re-projection errors?

Comment: I have no idea, I only started using openCV recently and just knew where to look for more information.

Comment: Same here. Thank your for your response. As mentioned by Micka it depends our coordinate system.

Comment: Your welcome :3 and remember to:  Pay it forward (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, vote up the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – **by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.**